# Can't connect to wired ethernet on Ubuntu 20

Tags: networking, ethernet

I can't connect to wired ethernet on Ubuntu 20.04.3 because it constantly pulling and unplugging (in network settings).
Win10 works just fine with the same cable and router, but if i boot linux even the LAN LED on the router is off.

I tried different LAN ports, and they work better (i can connect to network), but i can't even ping my router

My ifconfig if it helps:

```
enp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.86.79.185  netmask 255.255.192.0  broadcast 10.86.127.255
    inet6 fe80::b210:e402:d684:bc97  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 18:c0:4d:2d:ed:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4076  bytes 354083 (354.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4547  bytes 408368 (408.3 KB)
    TX errors 3  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 6952  bytes 661347 (661.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6952  bytes 661347 (661.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

sudo lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation Device 5013 (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller (rev 01)
02:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 01)
02:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge (rev 01)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
03:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
03:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
03:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
0a:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1)
0b:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
0c:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
0c:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
0c:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
0c:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
0d:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
0e:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
```

sudo lshw -c network:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 16
       serial: 18:c0:4d:2d:ed:b7
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.86.79.185 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:24 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7504000-f7504fff memory:f7500000-f7503fff
```

Comment: Your `lshw` output of "size: 100Mbit/s" suggests a cable problem... assuming that your switch/router/modem support 1G connections.

Comment: That's what I had thought at first when I had this issue a while back, I have the same ethernet controller as OP but it's just that r8169 has issues with our ethernet controller that's fixed in later versions of Ubuntu. I gave a workaround in my answer for 20.04.

Comment: Please clarify your OS & release; you mention 20 in the title which is a different Ubuntu product to 20.04.3 in your question (Ubuntu has used the *year* format to highlight *snap* only products since 2016 such as Ubuntu Core 20).  20 != 20.04

Answer (score 1):

If you can reach an internet connection via wifi or USB tethering a mobile device that supports it, try to install [r8168-dkms](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/r8168-dkms). This should be a temporary solution until r8169 that's provided in the kernel works properly on your device.

Try to run `sudo apt install r8168-dkms` and reboot. I have the same ethernet controller as you and this solves my problem most of the time. Mine works out of the box in 21.10 so the issue you're having is fixed in later versions of Ubuntu.